# Начальная установка wordpress. Database error

Tags: wordpress

Скачал чистый wordpress(с официального сайта), начал установку и вместо привычной стартовой страницы установки выводит: Ошибка установки соединения с базой данных. Хотя как раз в начальной установке должны указываться данные соединения с базой.

Локальный сервер MAMP. Все работало как нужно, а в этот раз появилась ошибка. Никак не пойму почему такое происходит. Можно и вручную редактировать wp-config-sample.php, потом поменять его название, но намного проще воспользоваться начальной установкой. Почему может возникать такая ошибка? Заранее благодарю за помощь:). Ниже перечень файлов. Абсолютно чистый wordpress, только скачанный с оф сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Перечень файлов wordpress

Comment: Можно понятней рассказывать? На начальной установке или всё же после редактирования образца? В первом случае (при отсутвии wp-config.php) просто не может быть подобной ошибки потому как там только задаются параметры конекта к БД.

Comment: @SeVlad Действительно, посмотрел нет ли wp-config, а оказывается он есть, но только не в этой директории, а на уровень выше и я не могу понять как wordpress мог его использовать, если на локальном сервере, я указал корневую папку именно с файлами чистого wordpress. А в папке на уровень выше лежал какой-то левый wp-config и из-за него не работало. Спасибо за помощь, теперь начальная установка работает:)

Comment: "_оказывается он есть, но только не в этой директории, а на уровень выше и я не могу понять как wordpress мог его использовать_". :) Это фича ВП. [Since Version 2.6, wp-config.php file can be moved to the directory directly above the WordPress install directory.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)